# The method 'signInWithAnonymously' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm getting this problem during I was creating sign in anonymously with the help of Firebase.

```dart
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthServices {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //sign in anonymous

  Future signInAnon() async {
    UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithAnonymously();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.signInAnonymously()`

```dart
  Future signInAnon() async {
    UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
  }
```

Comment: My bad it is so silly mistake but thank you so much..!!

Comment: Typo happens, you can check more on [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start)

Comment: User user  =result.user ;  I using this line just under the above line but I getting red line under the result.user